# Image not getting drawn on tkinter canvas

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I would like to display a knapsack image on green canvas. The height and width of that canvas is 250X250 pixels.

[image]

And the size of the image is 260X280 pixels.

[image]

When I try to execute below code, I get the output as shown in screenshot above [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU2fJ.png). The location of the code file and image file is same.

```
from tkinter.font import BOLD
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

def draw():
    global canvas
    root.geometry('1080x720')
    root.state('zoomed')

    canvas = Canvas(root,bg='black',highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

    sw = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    sh = root.winfo_screenheight()
    canvas.create_line(int(sw*0.0000),int(sh*0.1736),int(sw*0.6510),int(sh*0.1736),fill='white')
    canvas.create_line(int(sw*0.6510),int(sh*0.0000),int(sw*0.6510),int(sh*1.0000),fill='white')
    canvas.create_line(int(sw*0.6510),int(sh*0.1157),int(sw*1.0000),int(sh*0.1157),fill='white')
    canvas.create_line(int(sw*0.6510),int(sh*0.8101),int(sw*1.0000),int(sh*0.8101),fill='white')

    UI_frame1 = Frame(canvas,bg='black',width=int(sw*0.6510),height=int(sh*0.1580))
    canvas.create_window(0,0, anchor=NW,window=UI_frame1)
    
    N = Label(UI_frame1,text='N',bg ='black',fg='white',font=(12))
    N.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=139,pady=22)
    weights = Label(UI_frame1,text='Weights',bg ='black',fg='white',font=(12))
    weights.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=140,pady=22)
    val = Label(UI_frame1,text='Values',bg ='black',fg='white',font=(12))
    val.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=140,pady=22)
    
    n = Entry(UI_frame1,bg='white',width=4,font=(12))
    n.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=50,pady=17)
    value_arr = Entry(UI_frame1,bg='white',font=(12))
    value_arr.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=50,pady=17)
    weight_arr = Entry(UI_frame1,bg='white',font=(12))
    weight_arr.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=50,pady=17)

    Label(canvas,text='i',bg='black',fg='white',font=(14)).place(x=150,y=185)
    i = Label(canvas,text="  i  ",bg='white',font=(12)).place(x=175,y=185)
    Label(canvas,text='j',bg='black',fg='white',font=(14)).place(x=525,y=185)
    j = Label(canvas,text="  j  ",bg='white',font=(12)).place(x=550,y=185)


    table = Canvas(canvas,bg='red',width=600,height=450)
    table.place(x=75,y=300)

    w = int(600/8)
    h = int(450/5)
    x=0
    y=0
    for r in range(5):
        for c in range(8):
            table.create_rectangle(x,y,x+w,y+h)
            x+=w
        y+=h
        x=0
    
    UI_frame2 = Frame(canvas,bg='blue',width=250,height=250)
    canvas.create_window(835,630, anchor=CENTER,window=UI_frame2)

    image_c = Canvas(UI_frame2,bg='green',highlightthickness=0,width=250,height=250)
    image_c.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=0,pady=0)

    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file ='knapsack.png')
    image_c.create_image(835,630,image=photo,anchor=NW)


draw()
root.mainloop()
```

I would like to cover the entire green canvas with single image of knapsack. I am not any error while running the GUI. Anyone could help me out, I'll be really thankful.

Comment: If the canvas is just 250x250, why do you put the image at `(835, 630)` which is out of the viewable area of the canvas?

Comment: The coordinates '(865,630)' passed to create_image method are not with respect to root window? And I even tried passing '(0,0)', it did not work.

Comment: Of course it is not.  It is created inside the canvas, so the coordinates are inside the canvas.

Comment: @acw1668 I'm really thankful for helping me out. But I am not getting your point.

Comment: there is other common problem - there is bug in `PhotoImage` which removes image from memory when it is assigned to local variable in function - and then you can see emoty `PhotoImage`. You can use `global photo` to resolve this problem

Comment: It means that `(0, 0)` is the top-left corner of the canvas when it is used in `create_image(...)` (actually all `create_xxxx(...)` functions).

Comment: @furas and @acw1668 thankyou for your comments. Making the photo as global variable and assigning coordinates as `(0,0)`, the photo got displayed.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

**First:**

You display in position `(835,630)` but canvas has visible only `(250, 250)` - (top left corner is `(0,0)`) - so `photo` is in place which you can see.

**Second:**

There is bug in `PhotoImage()` which removes image from memory when it is assigned to local variable. One of solution is to use `global photo` to assign it to global variable.

```
def draw():
    global canvas
    global photo   # use global variable
    
    #... code ...

    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='knapsack.png')
    image_c.create_image(0, 0,image=photo, anchor=NW)   # position (0,0)
```

Doc (on archive.org): [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20200313162612/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) - see `Note` at the botton of doc.

[image]

Other problem can be that image has big (transparent) margins around object and it may show object in differnt place then you may expect.
Screenshot shows `photo` in position `(0,0)` but object is in center of green canvas.